# centralized Address/phone book able to sync with thunderbird

Tags: linux, database

In my office we are looking for a service able to store and manage all the phone numbers and adresses we have and capable of synchronize the database with clients (e.g. thunderbird) on personal computers.

The server is Linux/Debian. The clients are both Linux and Windows.

I know LDAP can do the job but are there some alternatives? Maybe smarter and capable of managing duplicated fields server side.

PS. I know Google can do it but we are trying to do it on our server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe use [radicale](http://radicale.org/), though I only use it daily for my agenda.

**Edit :** about security : [the documentation](http://radicale.org/user_documentation/#idauthentication) states that the authentification modules were not extensively tested, and that you should rely on a proper http server if it is a concern to you. I my case I nailed the problem by restricting access to the port on the router, which makes the calendar only accessible via ssh port forwarding. I believe this is probably not a viable solution in your case, and you will have to use a proper http server.

Comment: It seems what i need. I'm worried about security, is it safe? Does it create a security issues?